# What is ber_to_ascii_conversion.exe in VS2008 build folder?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am working on a Visual Studio C++ project and after compiling the project for Debug/Release I get two .exe files one of the project and second is

> ber_to_ascii_conversion.exe

Can any one explain why it is created and what is it for? Thanks

Comment: Guessing: BER is related to ASN.1, DER amd X.690 see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690 So the project is building a converter to ASCII.

Comment: I have just created a simple project why would the project build a converter to ASCII?